# Tracking Flight of a Bee or a Wasp

Tags: sensor, distance

I am planning to build a system that can track and present for me a path for the route a Bee or a Wasp has flown. What I am looking for is the tiny device can be placed on the back of an insect. Does such a device exist? If so what is it called?

Comment: Anything more than a few mg and tracking becomes easy as they won't be going anywhere.  Seems like a non-invasive way, like multi-camera video with fancy software would be better.  Reminds me of the old joke that ends with "frog with no legs: deaf".

Comment: I think a good way to do this may be to put a highly reflective dot on the back of the creature, and illuminate the room with (modulated) light -- Cameras can track that pretty easily. You may need to help the cameras by making sure the room is relatively matte.

Answer (score 10):

You'll find this stunningly apposite

2 orthogonal coils of about 100 turns (using 10 um diameter wire !!!) of 2mm diameter or less are mounted ob a blow fly and tracked in 3D space. They use a halter wity wired connection without impeding the blowfly's flight significantly. I have ideas (probably impractical) for a fully wireless version.

[image]

Photos from paper here:

[Using miniature sensor coils for simultaneous measurement of
orientation and position of small, fast-moving animals](http://iwi.eldoc.ub.rug.nl/FILES/root/1998/JNeurscMethSchilstra/1998JNeurosciMethSchilstra.pdf) Neurosci. Meth. 83, 125-131.

This is a related follow-up paper.
Not content wity the stunning initial result they mounted a second coil triplet on the blowfly's head so they could tell where it was looking while in flight.

[BLOWFLY FLIGHT AND OPTIC FLOW
II. HEAD MOVEMENTS DURING FLIGHT](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/202/11/1491.full.pdf)

Usefully related.

[AC magnetic field detection system applied to motion tracking](http://www.cedrat-technologies.com/fileadmin/user_upload/cedrat_groupe/Publications/Publications/2010/09/AC_magnetic_detection_SENSOR_2010.pdf)

Comment: +! Russell, that was amusing. ... and a brilliant find!